# UILocalNotification - Fire 30 minutes before an NSDate

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios4, nsdate, nsdateformatter, uilocalnotification

I am making an app that will fire a notification 30 minutes before an event. I calculate the NSDate and set the notification with this huge code: http://pastie.org/private/3n9z6c06i17i8h8giing

However, the notification never fires.
Could anyone please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that you've set the notification.fireDate as:

`[notification setFireDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:[remain second]]];`

But, your notification.timeZone doesn't appear to be set, so you're relying on the default?

Even though, you have:

`[parser setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:14400]];`

Try using this instead:

`notification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:14400];`